# Test for file on sd card - cached?

Tags: bash, debian, sd-card

I have a debian linux box with an SD card reader. It seems that I can do file IO (to a point) when the SD card isn't present. I need a way to ensure that the file that I'm reading is actually the one on the card and not from a cache.

Details: If I put a file on an SD card and read it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [-e "/media/usb3/disk_id"]
   id=`cat /media/usb3/disk_id`
   logger "disk id: $id"
else
   logger "not there"
fi
```

This works (IE expected behavior) if I insert a disk with the 'disk_id' file on it. *But* it continues to work if I remove the SD card... or put in another card that doesn't have the file on it.

I can detect the SD card presence / absence using `blkid -d /dev/null` but I'm not sure how to get around this caching that the OS is doing.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you unmount the card before pulling?

Comment: No. This is part of a test case.

Comment: It's up to the OS to flush in-memory structures when the media is removed. You can't reasonably expect your software to work properly when the OS is lying to it.

Comment: I'd consider this a bug in linux, it should have invalidated the cached files when the disk was removed, or a bug in the card reader (or possibly its driver), where the reader does not communicate the fact that the disk was removed. mounting with the `sync` option might help - but it might not be ideal for wearable flash devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove a device without unmounting it properly, you will observe this behavior.  There's really nothing you can do about it. At least nothing simple.

You could try to detect if the block device is present by writing something to it (perhaps creating a new file) then calling `fsync`.  If the block device is no longer there, the fsync will fail.

I'm not sure how to do that in a bash script, though.

You should just make sure you don't eject your SD cards without unmounting them first.